# how to make an object detector from an image classifier?

Tags: tensorflow, image-recognition, object-detection

I have a tensorflow model (retrained inception model) which can classify 5 classes of vehicles. Now i need to make an object detector for all these 5 classes with this trained model. Can it be done by removing the last layer ? can any one suggest me how to proceed further

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use your pretrained network, then you can detect potential boxes of interest then apply your network on each. These boxes can be determined with an "objectness" method, such as [EdgeBox](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/edge-boxes-locating-object-proposals-from-edges/).

However, on nowadays, object detection is usually obtained by a more integrated way, such those obtained with [faster RCNN](https://github.com/endernewton/tf-faster-rcnn). Such an approach integrates a layer named Region Proposal Network (RPN), that determine the region of interest, jointly with the recognition of the classes.

to the best of my knowledge, one of the best recent approaches is [Yolo](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/), but it is natively based on Darknet.

Comment: Thanks...i have tried YOLO and SSD...will try faster RCNN... i guess my idea is similar to a faster RCNN